# Razor html escaping on attribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am trying to create a the following tag using Razor but am having problems with html escaping.

```
<input type="button" value="Edit" onclick="EditOnClick('Name','Description')"/>
```

I have tried the following solutions

```
string onClick = string.Format("OnEdit(\'{0}\',\'{1}\')", item.Name, item.Description);
<input type="button" value="Edit" onclick="@Html.Raw(onClick)"/>
<input type="button" value="Edit" onclick="@(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(onClick))"/>
<input type="button" value="Edit" onclick="@(new HtmlString(Model.Content))"/>
```

Comment: What code does `onclick="@Html.Raw(onClick)"` actually generate on the client side? You mentioned `onclick="EditOnClick('Name','Description')"` but I can't see `EditOnClick` inside `string.Format` text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just do the following:

```
 <input type="button" value="Edit" onclick="EditOnClick('@item.Name', '@item.Description')"/>
```

or if they might have html in them:

```
 <input type="button" value="Edit" onclick="EditOnClick('@Html.Raw(item.Name)', '@Html.Raw(item.Description)')"/>
```

Comment: I feel like an idiot. The first one works fine, however, Razor flagged it as unterminated string constant with a red line so I thought it was an error. Thanks for your help.

Comment: No problem, glad I was able to help :)